# (odoo10) how to change line in pdf invoice

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

i'd like to change Description line in pdf invoice - i'd like to show product SCU instead of description.

here what i have in **report_invoice_document**:

```
<div class="row mt32 mb32"> <div class="col-xs-2" t-if="o.name"> <strong>Description:</strong> <p t-field=" <div class="row mt32 mb32"> <div class="col-xs-2" t-if="o.name"> <strong>Description:</strong> <p t-field="o.name"/> </div>"/> </div>
```

when i'm trying to change o.name to o.product_id - i'm getting 503 server error.

probably i missed something, pls advice how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to change `o.name` that refers to the name of the invoice record with `o.product_id` that it's not a field of the `account.invoice` model, it's a field of the `account.invoice.line` model that it's backed by the field `invoice_line_ids` on the `account.invoice` model.

You will need to use it for example to change the line:

```
<td><span t-field="l.name"/></td>
```

With:

```
<td><span t-field="l.product_id.name"/></td>
```